# Avoid duplicate method in two already extended classes implementing common interface in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been asked this question in a java interview but I could not find the answer anywhere.

```
X Y
| |
A B

Interface I{
m1();
}
```

Class A and Class B are extended from Class X and Class Y respectively.

X and Y cannot be changed. A and B implement interface I and method m1() has same definition in both.

How to avoid writing duplicate code.

Java 8 cannot be used since we can define methods in java-8 interfaces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe use a proxy ... :/

Comment: You can make a class C that has a function that does m1() and have an instance of C held by both A and B.  Of course that assumes the m1() implementation for both A and B are sufficiently similar that will work.  In which case your class hierarchy is probably wrong.  In the real world I wouldn't be spending much time worrying about this, this seems like a horrible question.

Comment: Delegate, delegate, delegate.

Comment: "Method m1 has the same definition in both" - that means that the method does not depend on any of the fields in A, B, X and Y (because then it wouldn't have the same definition). That's not a method that should be in the interface of either - it should be a static method that's not invoked through either A or B but directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an awful question, but a good way to go about it would be to make a static method (which holds the functionality of m1) in either `A.java` or `B.java`, and simply call that method in `A#m1` and `B#m1`.

This is a lot more simple than having to create another class.

A.java

```
@Override
public void m1() {
    methodHelper();
}

public static void methodHelper() {
    // Code goes here.
}
```

B.java

```
@Override
public void m1() {
    A.methodHelper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Gabe Sechan has to say.

Have another class (Class C) implement the m1() method defined in the interface.

Class A and Class B will both have an instance of Class C.  This will allow you to use that m1() method in which Class C implemented without having Class A and Class B have duplicate m1() methods.